# Strange InsertBoxR behaviour

Tags: floats

I am using `InsertBoxR` to add inline `tikzpicture` figures.  However, sometimes this gives strange results.  It depends on different factors, the length of text in particular.  After a lot of experimenting, I came up with a relatively simple example.  Hopefully, if you provide a solution for this problem, I will be able to solve the rest.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\lipsum[5]

\InsertBoxR{0}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\lipsum[6]

\lipsum[7]

\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem if you group the `\InsertBoxR` command and the shortened paragraph with a pair of braces:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,parskip=half]{scrbook}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \input{insbox}

    \begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[2]

    \lipsum[3]

    \lipsum[4]

    \lipsum[5]

    {\InsertBoxR{0}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \lipsum[6]}

    \lipsum[7]

    \lipsum[8]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Works and makes sense.